# creating AMF files for caching

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, amf

I would like to create some AMF files for caching on a server.

I am wondering if the best approach is to reconfigure BlazeDS to create these files so it spits out local files (is there a tutorial or suggestions on how to do this)?

Or if is possible to use as3 itself to create the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the files in as3 by building your objects then using ByteArray.writeObject() and save the resulting ByteArray using FileReference Class.